# How to rebuild Qt?

Tags: qt

I've got Qt 5.13.0 on unbuntu 16.04 downloaded from the online installer. I have modified 5.13.0/Src/qtdatavis3d/src/datavisualization/utils/texturehelper.cpp. How do I rebuild all of the Qt libraries, etc to incorporate this change in my apps? I do not see a Makefile at the top level...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the beginning:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html

The source distribution for your system will include the tools and steps for compiling.